# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Element not allowed

Tags: java, itext

I am facing one problem , I am using the following library in my program to convert Html to pdf.

itextpdf.jar - 5.4.1 version

xmlworker - 5.4.1 version

I tested my code for so many HTMLs and it is working fine, but one of the HTMLs is not working and throwing the following exception.. Please look into that and let mw know if you guys know any solution.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Element not allowed.  at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.addElement(ColumnText.java:471)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell.addElement(PdfPCell.java:283)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.table.TableData.end(TableData.java:151)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.endElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:189)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.close(HtmlPipeline.java:206)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.endElement(XMLWorker.java:141)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.endElement(XMLParser.java:395)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.process(ClosingTagState.java:70)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:235)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:213)
 at com.cisco.wem.transformation.HtmlProcessor.generatePDF(HtmlProcessor.java:1728)
 at com.cisco.wem.transformation.HtmlProcessor.processHtml(HtmlProcessor.java:292)
 at com.cisco.wem.transformation.HtmlProcessor.execute(HtmlProcessor.java:207)
 at com.cisco.wem.transformation.HtmlProcessor.run(HtmlProcessor.java:1451)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I saw one of the blogs and they said to use the following snippet but I am not sure where to use that in my code

```
for (Element e : elements) {
     if (!ColumnText.isAllowedElement(e))
         continue;
     // do stuff
}
```

This is my code:

```
public String generatePDF(String tempFolder,String completeHtmlFilePath,NodeBO renditionRequestBO)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, DocumentException,
 CssResolverException {

  << some code stuff here>>

  com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
   new FileOutputStream(pdfFileNameWithPath));
  document.open();

  HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
  //htmlContext.setLastMarginBottom(100.0f);
  htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
  CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance()
    .getDefaultCssResolver(true);


  Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
    new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document,
      writer)));

  XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);


  XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

  File input = new File(completeHtmlFilePath);
  p.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(input), "UTF-8"));

  document.close();

  return pdfFileNameWithPath;


 }
}
```

Thanks
Sri

This is the HTML code snippet I getting this exception, you can take only table element below.

```html
<pre><code><table class="stepTable" border="0" cellpadding="3"  
cellspacing="0"     
width="90%"><ol><tr><td align="left" valign="top"><b>Step 1</b>  
 </td><td valign="top" class="stepexpand">
 <a name="F3BD336EF5F6499EAB5C6A39AA81852F"><!-- --></a><span>Log in to Cisco
 CCO 
 <a href="http://www.cisco.com/cgi-bin/tablebuild.pl/sccm"  
target="_blank">http:/​/​www.cisco.com/​cgi-bin/​tablebuild.pl/​sccm</a>. 
 </span></td></tr>
 <tr><td align="left" valign="top"><b>Step 2</b>  
 </td><td valign="top" class="stepexpand"><a name="24BB6E38029E4A7493CE85443C212D09"><!-- --></a><span>Enter your Cisco
 CCO password when prompted. 
 </span></td></tr>
 <tr><td align="left" valign="top"><b>Step 3</b>  
 </td><td valign="top" class="stepexpand"><a name="step_C3603915B0C2485684A1AD73989307D9">
 <!-- -- ></a><span><span>Download the SCMS-CM
Installation software package (scms-cm-v500-b100-linux-64.tar).</span> 
</span><br/></td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top"><b>Step 4</b>  
</td><td valign="top" class="stepexpand"><a  
name="4818AB7377474E80824041ED0C3F240B"><!-- --></a><span>Extract the
 package into a temporary directory. 
 </span>  
 <br/><br/><b>Example:</b> 
 <pre class="codeblock"># 
 <kbd  class="userinput"><b>mkdir /usr/tmp/cm_install_temp</b></kbd></pre>
 <br/><br/><b>Example:</b> 
 <pre class="codeblock"># 
 <kbd  class="userinput"><b>cd /usr/tmp/cm_install_temp</b></kbd></pre>
 <br/><br/><b>Example:</b> 
 <pre class="codeblock"># <kbd class="userinput"><b>tar  
 xvf ../cm_full_package.tar</b></kbd></pre>
 </td></tr> test
 </ol></table></code></pre>
```

Comment: Can you paste the html code? There must be some illegal element in the html.

- addElement - line 471

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.3.4/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ColumnText.java#ColumnText.addElement%28com.itextpdf.text.Element%29

Comment: It might be an HTML vs XHTML issue. iText needs its input to be XHTML which is stricter than HTML. If you post your HTML we will be able to help you.

Comment: for example <br> is not allowed

Comment: Thanks James for editing.

Answer (score 2):

It might be an HTML vs XHTML issue. iText needs its input to be XHTML which is stricter than HTML. For example the br element is not allowed. Also you need to close your elements correctly.

You can convert your HTML to XHTML before sending it to iText using the open source project "Tidy" http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

```
public static String convertHtmlToXhtml(String html) {
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); 
    tidy.setXHTML(true); 
    tidy.setDocType("omit");
    InputStream inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream(html);
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    tidy.parse(inputStream, outputStream); 
    return outputStream.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks lot all, I will make the HTML well-formed and try that. Will let you know.

Comment: Hi Onur Aktaş & All,  I converted the HTML to XHTML by using one online URL but still same error. I would like to paste the HTML here but this UI has a limit up to 30000 characters but my HTML file is almost 93000 characters. Is there any other way to share HTML with you.? please let me know. Thanks. Sri

Comment: Perhaps you could try removing parts of the html until you find the specific element that is the problem. e.g a binary search, remove the bottom half of the html and test, if the problem persists you know it is in the top half, if not you know it is in the bottom half, repeat.

Comment: Hi  bhspencer, I tested the HTML by taking parts of the HTML and pin pointed the issue like wherever <table> tag is there in HTML this issue is coming. I am wondering how itext is not supporting <table>, any thoughts on that, please share.

Comment: Could you construct a minimal html document that demonstrates the problem and include it in your question.

Comment: Hi bhspencer, please find the HTML code snippet appended to my question above , please take <table> tag where I got this exception, appreciate if you could look into that (the HTML starts <pre><code>...., consider only table element)

Comment: Hi All, any suggestions here why iText is throwing exception with table element, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Hi bhspencer, I would like to hear from you any suggestions. Thanks